# How to fix a button at the bottom of the tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, tablefooterview

In my App i want to fix a button at the bottom of the table view.

Here is my Initial Screen,

[image]

Button created at the footer section

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(tableView == educateTbl) 
{
    float footerWidth = 150.0f;
    float padding = 10.0f;
    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, footerWidth, 50.0)];
    footerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    UIButton *addEdu = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(padding, 0, footerWidth - 2.0f * padding, 44.0f)];
    addEdu.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    addEdu.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

    [addEdu setTitle:@"Add Education" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [addEdu addTarget:self action:@selector(addEducation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [addEdu setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    addEdu.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30); 
    [footerView addSubview:addEdu];
    return footerView;
}
return nil;
}
```

After that i am getting like this,

[image]

How can i fix that?

Comment: add constraint in button

Comment: I'd suggest creating a view and set it as `tableView.tableFooterView`.

Comment: The above code will set the footer view for particular section. Try to set the view as tableFooterView like this, **self.tableView.tableFooterView = addEdu;**

Comment: Did you implement `-tableView:heightForFooterInSection:`, too?

Comment: set different background colour for footer view. so that you can get an idea about the frame size and where it is placed

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad. footer section height = 30.of

Comment: @User558 while scrolling this button is visible at some other row (or) its didn't get placed bottom of your footer ?

Comment: @KishoreKumar while scrolling this button is visible at some row.i want to fix at bottom of the tableview, see my 1st image

Comment: @User558 see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why you dont make something like this?

```
-(void)setTableFooter
{
   float footerWidth = 150.0f;
   float padding = 10.0f;
   UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, footerWidth, 50.0)];
   footerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

   UIButton *addEdu = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(padding, 0, footerWidth - 2.0f * padding, 44.0f)];
   addEdu.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
   addEdu.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

   [addEdu setTitle:@"Add Education" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [addEdu addTarget:self action:@selector(addEducation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [addEdu setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
addEdu.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30); 
   [footerView addSubview:addEdu];

   tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;

}
```

and call this after you init the table

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)CreateCustomFooter
{
   float footerWidth = 150.0f;
   float padding = 10.0f;
   UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, footerWidth, 50.0)];
   footerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

   UIButton *addEdu = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(padding, 0, footerWidth - 2.0f * padding, 44.0f)];
   addEdu.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
   addEdu.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

   [addEdu setTitle:@"Add Education" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [addEdu addTarget:self action:@selector(addEducation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [addEdu setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
addEdu.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30); 
   [footerView addSubview:addEdu];

   tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;

}
```

Put above method in viewDidLoad() Method and after initializing tableview

Comment: addEdu.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    addEdu.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter; 
remove above code then try.........

Comment: Hello dear, Simply try this set image only to your footer view then let me know whats happen's.Please refer my above edited answer

Comment: it is showing image over the tableview.not fixed at bottom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109873/discussion-between-user558-and-hitesh-surani).

Answer (score 0):

If you want section footer/header scroll with tableview, you need to use a grouped style table view.

`[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped]`

And a grouped style table view will have a default backgroundColor and section header/footer height. You need set these value explicitly.

If you have only one section, it is better to use `tableFooterView` instead of section footer view

Answer (score 0):

While Scrolling that button visible means ,UITableview cell are reusable so that button is available ,what you have to do means .

1.Take number of row in UITableView ,

**Then inside cell for row at indexpath :**

```
Total number of row ==indexpath.row
{
   //inside this button.hidden=no;
}
else
{
   //button.hidden=yes;
}
```